# Slice not working on dask chunked xarray's

Tags: python, slice, dask, python-xarray

I have a large xarray which has time, y and x dimensions and is in dask chunks of time = 1, x = 2000, y = 2000. It looks something like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 59, x: 6951, y: 6963)
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 5.193e+06 5.193e+06 5.193e+06 ... 5.298e+06 5.298e+06
  * x        (x) float64 7.475e+05 7.476e+05 7.476e+05 ... 8.518e+05 8.518e+05
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-11-11T03:51:53 ... 2018-02-27T03:40:41
Data variables:
    green    (time, y, x) uint16 dask.array<shape=(59, 6963, 6951), chunksize=(2, 1000, 1000)>
    swir_1   (time, y, x) uint16 dask.array<shape=(59, 6963, 6951), chunksize=(2, 1000, 1000)>
    mask     (time, y, x) int8 dask.array<shape=(59, 6963, 6951), chunksize=(2, 1000, 1000)>
Attributes:
    crs:      EPSG:32648
```

I'm trying to slice this code, so I can perform computations on a small part of it iteratively and create a new xarray at the end (due to having problems with the speed of doing .compute() on it). I've been trying variants around:

```
data.sel(x=slice(0,100),y=slice(0,100))
```

But this (and similar variants) just produce:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 59, x: 0, y: 0)
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 
  * x        (x) float64 
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-11-11T03:51:53 ... 2018-02-27T03:40:41
Data variables:
    green    (time, y, x) uint16 dask.array<shape=(59, 0, 0), chunksize=(2, 0, 0)>
    swir_1   (time, y, x) uint16 dask.array<shape=(59, 0, 0), chunksize=(2, 0, 0)>
    mask     (time, y, x) int8 dask.array<shape=(59, 0, 0), chunksize=(2, 0, 0)>
Attributes:
    crs:      EPSG:32648
```

Is this problem caused by trying to do slicing on a chunked array? I've tried lining up the chunk size to be the same as the slice as well, but this has produced a similar problem. Ideally I just want to use the dask framework of the xarray's to do computations (such as creating indices and sums) of the data in parallel, but I haven't been able to get that to work, or at least, any computes take a long time (30+ mins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xarray has two selection methods, [`.sel()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.sel.html#xarray.Dataset.sel) and [`.isel()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.isel.html#xarray.Dataset.isel). `.sel()` selects based on tick labels along the specified dimensions. `.isel()` selects based on integer positions along the specified dimensions.

In your case, it looks like you either want to use `.isel()`

```
# select a 100x100 window 
data.isel(x=slice(7.475e+05, 7.700e+05), y=slice(5.190e+06, 5.195+06))
```

or a `.sel()` with tick labels that correspond to x and y (instead of integers)

```
# select a window based on x/y values 
data.sel(x=slice(0, 100), y=slice(0,100))
```

*Side note: its hard to say but the performance problems with dask are hopefully unrelated to this question.*

Comment: don't know what I was doing wrong before, as our .sel lines seem to be identical. Either way it's working now!